# Calculate the location of the bones in Blender from BVH

Tags: python, pose-mode, path, inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics

I know that `bpy.ops.pose.paths_calculate` can be used to calculate the position of a bone at any time, but I don’t know the details. My task is as follows: first, a BVH is given, which I import into Blender. I want to deduce the location of the head and tail of each bone in each frame using only the raw data in the BVH (in world coordinates). Does anyone know how to do this? Or can someone provide the source code for `bpy.ops.pose.paths_calculate`? Thank you in advance!”